# Exclude some sheets from hiding in For Each function

Tags: excel, vba

I use this `VBA` to make all sheets invisible except for `Sheet1`, `Sheet5` and `Sheet8`:

```
Sub Invisible_Version_01 ()
Dim b As Worksheet
For Each b In Worksheets
    If b.CodeName <> "Sheet1" _
    And b.CodeName <> "Sheet5" _
    And b.CodeName <> "Sheet8" _
    Then
    b.Visible = False
    End If
Next b
End Sub
```

All this works perfectly.

---

Now, I want to do it the other way around which means **all sheets should be visible except** for `Sheet1`, `Sheet5` and `Sheet8`. Therefore, I tried to go with this `VBA`:

```
Sub Invisible_Version_02 ()
Dim b As Worksheet
For Each b In Worksheets
    If b.CodeName = "Sheet1" _
    And b.CodeName = "Sheet5" _
    And b.CodeName = "Sheet8" _
    Then
    b.Visible = False
    End If
Next b
End Sub
```

However, when I run this code nothing at all happens. 
How do I need to modify the `VBA` to hide the `Sheet1`, `Sheet2` and `Sheet3`?

Comment: A sheet can *not* be named three different names at once. You are currently checking if a sheet is named "Sheet1", "Sheet4" **and** "Sheet8". That being said, maybe a nice usecase for `Select Case`.

Comment: Replace all `AND` with `OR` for the second sub

Comment: Keep your above code like it is and only change `b.Visible = False` with `b.Visible = True`... If you want them to be hidden, just add `Else b.Visible = False`. I am not sure you exactly understand what I meant. I will post the code like an answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way, please:

```
Sub Invisible_Version_01 ()
Dim b As Worksheet
For Each b In Worksheets
    If b.CodeName <> "Sheet1" _
        And b.CodeName <> "Sheet5" _
        And b.CodeName <> "Sheet8" _
                                  Then
       b.Visible = True
    Else
       b.Visible = False
    End If
Next b
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3):

You currently are checking a name against three options using **and**, meaning *only* when a sheet's name equals all three options visibility will be set to `False`. Needless to say this would never happen. Could be solved through changing to `Or`, but I think this could be a good usecase for `Select Case`, try:

```
Sub Invisible_Version_02()

Dim ws As Worksheet
For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    Select Case ws.CodeName
        Case "Sheet1", "Sheet5", "Sheet8"
            ws.Visible = False
        Case Else
            ws.Visible = True
    End Select
Next

End Sub
```

This would loop over all worksheets and will make sure those that were hidden in the first place become visible again if need be.